# How to predict multiple attributes in java using weka api?

Tags: java, weka, prediction

I have a question about how to make multiple attribute predictions using weka in java.

I have this dataset:

```
MONTH,LOC,CLASS,METHOD,MGOD,CGOD
1,2115,9,192,1,1
2,2115,9,192,1,1
3,2115,9,192,1,1
4,2387,9,210,2,1
5,2356,9,208,2,1
6,2356,9,208,2,1
7,2510,9,219,2,2
8,2348,9,206,2,1
9,2356,9,206,2,1
10,2356,9,206,2,1
11,2051,7,172,2,0
12,2051,7,172,2,0
13,2048,7,172,2,0
14,2048,7,172,2,0
15,2083,7,173,1,0
16,2083,7,173,1,0
17,2143,7,171,1,0
18,2143,7,171,1,0
19,1909,7,155,1,0
20,1909,7,155,1,0
21,1909,7,155,1,0
22,1909,7,155,1,0
23,1909,7,155,1,0
24,1820,6,156,1,0
25,1826,6,157,1,0
26,1826,6,157,1,0
27,1826,6,157,1,0
```

I would like to make a prediction for month 28 based on the previous months.

My code:

```
    DataSource ds = new DataSource("src/main/java/dataset.arff");
    Instances inst = ds.getDataSet();
    inst.setClassIndex(1);
    LinearRegression  nb = new LinearRegression();
    nb.buildClassifier(inst);
    Instance novo = new DenseInstance(6);
    novo.setDataset(inst);
    novo.setValue(0, 28);

    double prediction[] = nb.distributionForInstance(novo);

    System.out.println("Prediction: "+Math.round(prediction[0]));
```